# Un-mash a string in C++ using recursion

Tags: c++, string, recursion

Part A: Have a user input a string. Then display this string smashed up as follows: display the first character in the string, then the last, then the second, then the second to last, then the third... So if the string is “abcdef”, it will display:
afbecd (input “abcdef”) 
12345 --> 15243
123456 --> 162534

Part B: Now, unmash the above strings. 
i.e 162534 -->123456

I got part A to work.

```
  #include <iostream>
  using namespace std;
  void mash(string s);

  int main()
  {
  string sequence;
  cout << "Enter a sequence: ";
  getline(cin, sequence);
  mash(sequence);
  }

  void mash(string s)
  {
  int a = s.length();

  if (a == 0)
  {
  return;
  }
  if (a == 1)
  {
  cout << s;
  return;
  }

  cout << s[0]; 

  if(a>1)
  { 
  cout << s[a - 1]; 
  s = s.substr(1,a-2);
  mash(s);
  }
 }
```

but I have no clue how to approach part B. I guess I can try to print out the characters in the even position, say in the string 162534, thus I will get 123. Then I guess I can try to print out the odd position characters from the last one up to the first one, i.e, 456. Combining these two will get the original strings but I have no clue how to use recursion to solve part B.

Comment: Hint: what is unmash("2534") and how does it relate to unmash("162534")?

Comment: I guess I want to move 5, which is the second character to the end of the string in "2534" and also 6 to end also in "162534"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a hint. So `unmash(string s)` should first print the first character `s[0]`, then `unmash(s.substr(2, length - 2))`, then `s[1]`. Of course, you also need to check if `length <= 2` need to treat that differently.

Comment: Shouldn't that be just `unmash(s.substr(2))`?

Comment: @0x499602D2 yes my bad. corrected it.

Comment: @grigor Thanks so much for helping me out. Do you think we need to care for the case n <= 2? Because I think the recursion will take care of that part.

Comment: @Hugh Happy to help. Yes you need to take care of n <= 2 separately. I mean if you're accessing s[0] and s[1] you need to make sure that the string is of length 2 at least. Something like: `if(n == 0) return;` `if(n == 1) { cout << s[0]; return; }`.

Comment: @grigor I have a quick question. If we start the string at position 2 after printing out s[0], what about s[1]? Let's say I have a string "162534". First of all, I cout << s[0], then I call the recursive function unmash(s.substr(2)), which will take a substring start at position 2, which is "2534". What would be the best way to understand how number 6 will be included eventually? Thanks!

Comment: @Hugh You print s[1] (i.e. number 6 in your example) at the very end, so that's how it's included. Not sure if I can give any better intuition. It's the reverse of mash. For mash you put the first then the last and so on, so the last will be in position 1. So when you unmash you have to put the position 1 symbol at the very end.

Comment: @grigor Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer an it works perfectly thanks to all of the members of SO who helped me.

```
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;
 void unmash(string s);

 int main()
 {
 string sequence;
 cout << "Enter a sequence: ";
 getline(cin, sequence);
 unmash(sequence);
 }

void unmash(string s)
{
 int a = s.length();

 if (a == 0)
 {
 return;
 }

 if (a == 1||a == 2)
 {
 cout << s;
 return;
 }

cout << s[0];   

 if(a>1)
 {          
    unmash(s.substr(2));
    cout << s[1];   
 }
}
```